# JQuery: Loop through multiple lists and hide more than 5 children for each

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which contains unordered lists with dozens of list items in each list. The lists share the same class. I want to loop through each list and if it has more than 5 list items I want to show the top 5 and hide the rest and display a link to another page.

I am having trouble with the logic as I am only able to do what I stated above with the first unordered list and am subsequently hiding every other list that follows. How do check each list and break if there aren't more than 5 rows and continue to the next one?

Below is the basic HTML and JS that I've tried.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
 $('ul.resultsList').each(function () { 
          if($(this).children().length > 4) {
   $('li:gt(4)').hide();
   $('.seeMore').show();
  }else {
                        $('.seeMore').hide();
                        return false;
                }
 });
```

```html
    <table id="docResults">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Names</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <ul class="resultsList">
     <li>Smith, J</li>
     <li>Smith, F</li>
     <li>Smith, K</li>
     <li>Smith, L</li>
     <li>Smith, M</li>
     <li>Smith, N</li>
     <li>Smith, O</li>
     <li>Smith, P</li>
     <li>Smith, Q</li>
     <li>Smith, R</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="seeMore">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <ul class="resultsList">
     <li>Smith, J</li>
     <li>Smith, F</li>
     <li>Smith, K</li>
     <li>Smith, L</li>
     <li>Smith, M</li>
     <li>Smith, N</li>
     <li>Smith, O</li>
     <li>Smith, P</li>
     <li>Smith, Q</li>
     <li>Smith, R</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="seeMore">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$(this)` object at this context for invoking `.hide()`

```
$('ul.resultsList').each(function () { 
 var td = $(this).closest("td");
 if($(this).children().length > 4) {
   $('li:gt(4)', this).hide();
   $('.seeMore', td).show(); 
 }else {
   $('.seeMore', td).hide();
 }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c2oxw1kz/)

Comment: Thank you @rajaprabhu-aravindasamy! It totally worked!